# Phone background app persistent connection

Tags: ios, sockets, websocket, push

Im achitecturing a mini distributed app where one of the important modules is installed on the phone[ios app]. This means the phone will always have to be on, and not in the background.
With these im using dissident[jailbreak] true backgrounding tweak to simplify that. If connection is lost, the phone app resets it.
The constant communication will be initiated by server for a resource on the phone if the phone is registered as active on the server.
My issue is the connection type and the only technology am considering is websocket. will it be so efficient and advisable. The phone should work 24/7 with no human intervention.

Comment: Please  on tag your question with the relevant tags, since the question is about iOS the tag android & windows phone should be removed. Also this question will not yield any usable results since it is very dependent on users opinion.